# What is the German translation of "catenary ring"?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, terminology, translation

I am looking for the correct technical term in German for the notion of *catenary ring* in commutative algebra.

Does anyone know?

> For those who don't know what a catenary ring is but would like to: A Noetherian commutative ring A is called *catenary* if the following codimension formula holds for irreducible closed subsets T ⊆ Y ⊆ Z of Spec A:
>
> > codim(T, Z) = codim(T, Y) + codim (Y, Z).

Comment: I have learned that it's called "katenär" in german.

Comment: Do you know whether this is the correct technical term (as it looks like a made-up word one will not find in a German dictionary) or whether it is just being used by someone who also does not know how to translate "catenary" properly?

Comment: @Hanno: Wow, entering "katenär" in google gives 16 hits (already including your answer :)). I have never heard/seen this word; but on the one hand I never talked about these rings in German and on the other hand google books gives at least 3 relevant hits, so it seems that some mathematicians indeed use it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be "Kettenring", see for example p. 148 in [Brodmann, Algebraische Geometrie](http://books.google.com/books?id=agw3I3IwUDMC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=kettenring+primideal&source=bl&ots=M3d7_XqnGb&sig=mFjpisRgp5tnpwnRj0ub45HzTTQ&hl=en&ei=vgTQS8zKNYOQOI7xnZ0P&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=kettenring&f=false).

Comment: This makes sense because "catenary" is just the Latin-derived English word for "chain", so German should use its own word for "chain".

Answer (score 0):

according to [this German Maths Dictionary](http://henked.de/maple/dictionary), it's 'kettenlinie'

Comment: This doesn't make sense. In English, "catenary" can also stand for a curve given by the graph of the cosh function, so it can be used as a noun (in this case) or as an adjective (in the case of catenary rings). In German, "Kettenlinie" is just a noun, so it cannot stand in front of the word "ring". Furthermore, the meaning of "Kettenlinie" is exactly the meaning of the English catenary when it stands for the curve; and the meaning of "Kettenlinie" doesn't have anything to do with chains of prime ideals.


Comment: Don't you think it a little unfair downvoting the answer? The original question title was "What is the German translation of "catenary"" - it was then changed to "catenary ring".